# How do I create an object that already exists in the Hierarchy in Unity C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, destroy

I have a character that when it touches another object(lava), it is destroyed.
Upon death, there will be a GUI that creates a respawn button, but how do I re-create the player object? I destroyed the object with Destroy(collision.gameObject);

Answer (score 1):

The way I would approach your problem would **not** be to destroy the player when it touches the lava, but rather **deactivate** the object. Then, when the user clicks the respawn button you would simply activate the object again (but make sure to take him out of the lava first).

[This](http://unity3d.com/support/documentation/ScriptReference/GameObject-active.html) might help for the code-side of things.

Answer (score 0):

[Instantiate](http://unity3d.com/support/documentation/ScriptReference/Object.Instantiate.html) should do the trick.